# Include headers file problem when using mongocxx-driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

driver and I have some questions about using the driver. The question is about which header files should I inlcude for using this driver in my project? I have seen this kind of include files

```
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
```

and this kind of include files

```
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.cpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
```

I am confused about what header files should I include.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

mongocxx-driver has many features and you aren't likely to be using all of them, include the headers you need for the features you are using.

The [documentation](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/) seems to be broken at the moment but it tells you which headers to include for each class.

Comment: What appears to be broken in the docs? Can you open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/CXX